# Error migrating from GeneXus 9 to GeneXus Evo 2 U5

Tags: migration, genexus

I'm migrating a KB from GeneXus 9 to GeneXus Evo 2 U5. I'm using .Net and SQL Server, and followed the steps that are mentioned in GXTechnical but I have the following error:

```
========== DeveloperMenu Compilation started ==========
gxexec "C:\Modelos GX\Postulantes\DATAPROT\bldDevelopermenu.cs" -r:GxBaseBuilder.dll -arg:csc="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe" -arg:mdlpath="C:\Modelos GX\Postulantes\DATAPROT"

Building bin\messages.spa.dll
Read in 570 resources from 'messages.spa.txt'
Writing resource file...  Done.
Compilador de Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2008, versi¢n 3.5.30729.5420 para Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, versi¢n 3.5
(C) Microsoft Corporation. Reservados todos los derechos.
Error:Build error for target bin\GeneXus.Programs.Common.dll: .\GxObjectCollection.cs does not exist.
DeveloperMenu Compilation Failed

========== Assemblies Compilation started ==========
gxexec "C:\Modelos GX\Postulantes\DATAPROT\bldAssemblies.cs" -r:GxBaseBuilder.dll -arg:csc="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe" /noconfig -arg:mdlpath="C:\Modelos GX\Postulantes\DATAPROT"
Error:Build error for target bin\GeneXus.Programs.Common.dll: .\GxObjectCollection.cs does not exist.
Assemblies Compilation Failed
Rebuild All Failed
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you add a link to the steps you followed from GXTechnical?

Comment: this is the link http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?Converting+a+KB+From+GeneXus+9.0+%28or+prior%29+To+GeneXus+X+%2F+X+Evo+1+%2F+X+Evo+2+%2F+X+Evo+3, i was wrong and it's from the wiki and not from GXTechnical, i did what Armin Bachmann said but it didn't work. i did a build all and the kb is working now, but if i do a re all build all, it has the same error

Answer (score 2):

Try these steps:

1. In GeneXus, go to Tools -> Explore Knowledgebase Directory
2. Delete all *.ari, *.0?? files
3. In GeneXus, go to Tools -> Explore Target Environment Directory
4. Delete that folder
5. In GeneXus, go to Build -> Rebuild All

If you keep having the same error, look at the entire output; there may be other errors before that one. If not, contact the GeneXus support team. If yes, search in google or search.genexus.com for solutions of that new errors.